# Angular url tree hide url

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to use an auth guard on a home page and if the user is not logged in, it creates a url tree and routes the user to the login page. I would like it to do the routing but not append /login to the url. Something like this I thought I could do:

```
return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

But I checked the docs and it doesn't look like urlTree can take skipLocationChange as an additional argument. Is there any other way to do this and hide the location change?

Comment: Why would you want to hide `login` url? Is it a vulnerability? :)

Comment: According to the [`docs`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createurltree), what you wrote down should work. Did you try?

Comment: @PierreDuc yea it routes to /login in the address bar.

Comment: try `this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { skipLocationChange: true })`

Comment: @Sergey auth guard has to return a url tree or promise, can't do navigateByUrl

Comment: Return false and navigate before?

Comment: In my app I simply do `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/']); return false;` and this works.